# Using custom controls with Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, interface-builder

I have a custom  ViewController which allows selection of an image from a grid. The ViewController uses the AQGrid control and is really just a modified version of the samples shipped with AQGrid.

I'm trying to hook it up in InterfaceBuilder, but documentation on how to do this seems sparse. In standard Cocoa apparently I should create an IB plugin to use with IB, but I'm just looking for the quickest option really as there are a few of these custom ViewControllers which I need to hook up (including a rating control). I've also tried dragging the "Object" controller in IB to my tabpage, but it just gets added to the tree outside of the tabcontroller (see screenshot).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: It seem by the way it looks (stripes) that your view controller named General doesn't have its `view` defined. This may lead to some unwanted effects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, you have to add a generic `UIViewController` to your nib file and then change its class in the Identity inspector to whatever you need as long as it's a subclass of `UIViewController`.

Comment: But how does that let you use the View from the ViewController in Interface Builder?  I'd like to do it in IB and not programmatically lay it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use a "Custom View" object and assign the appropriate class in the inspector's info tab. Using Interface Builder plugins isn't really advisable anymore, because Xcode 4 doesn't support them.

Comment: Where would I find said "Custom View" object in XCode 4's storyboard editor?

Comment: It's just called "View" now.